# Simpson's Rule Via Table

Tags: calculus, simpsons-rule

Alright, so I'm a bit stumped on this one. I learned Simpson's rule via my textbook as follows:

> $$\frac{h}{3}[y_0 + y_n + 2(y_2+y_4+...+y_{n-2}) + 4(y_1+y_3+...+y_{n-1})]$$

I was given a problem in my book as follows:

> Given the following data on $y = f(x)$,
>
> $$\begin{array}{c|c} 
>  \text{x} & \text{y} \\ \hline
> 0 & 32 \\ \hline
> 1 & 38 \\ \hline
> 2 & 29 \\ \hline
> 3 & 33 \\ \hline
> 4 & 42 \\ \hline
> 5 & 44 \\ \hline
> 6 & 38 \\ \hline
> \end{array}$$
>
> Calculate approximately $\int_{0}^6 f(x) dx$.

I plugged in the numbers into the formula as follows with $h = 1$:

$$\frac{1}{3}[32+38+2(29+42)+4(38+33+44)]$$

When I solve the formula I get 224 as my answer, but my book says the answer is 37.33 (somehow).

If anyone can point out my mistake that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit: 37.33 not 33.37

Comment: Your answer looks correct, though $\int_0^6 f(x)dx/\int_0^6dx\approx 37.33$

Comment: I'm sorry I don't follow. What do you mean by $\int_{0}^6 f(x)dx/\int_{0}^6 dx \approx 37.33$?

Comment: I mean $\int_0^6 f(x)dx/(6-0)\approx224/6\approx 37.33$; did the book say $33.37$ or $37.33$?

Comment: It said 33.37 as the answer.

Comment: However, why would we divide the integral by 6? Shouldn't the rule above provide a good approximation of the area?

Comment: Yes it should, which is why I said your answer looks correct; I can tell just by looking at the numbers that the area should be six times thirty-something

Comment: 37.33 would provide an approximation to the average height (=area/width)

Comment: So I guess that means that my book is wrong then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your book says what you say it does, then I agree with you over your book.

Using Simpson's rule, $\int_0^6 f(x)dx\approx 224.$

For comparison, using the trapezoidal rule, the answer would be $\int_0^6 f(x)dx\approx \frac12(6)(32+38)=210.$

For some reason, the answer in the book apparently divided by $\int_0^6 dx=6$.

Comment: For another comparison, using the midpoint rule, the answer would be $\int_0^6f(x)dx\approx6\times38=228$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the book is wrong.  You have implemented the rule correctly.  As in the comments, the book is dividing by $6$, but just an eyeball average says the function is somewhere in the range of $35-40$ and the interval is $6$, so the area is somewhere in the range $210-240$.  Your result is squarely inside this bound, while the book is not.